# Error while publish websphere portal server

Tags: java, websphere, websphere-portal

I am facing the following error due to which my server is not able to publish even after 30-40 mins time.

The problem I am facing is :

```
SystemErr     R com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.AdminException: ADMA5046E: No cell name is specified in the options table that is  passed as a parameter to the intallApplication API.  
The cell name is looked for in the module to server mapping that is specified using the AppConstants.APPDEPL_MODULE_TO_SERVER key in the options table and then in the value that corresponds to the AppConstants.APPDEPL_CELL key in the options table.
[5/19/14 17:28:18:052 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.updateAppAndCellName(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:330)
[5/19/14 17:28:18:052 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.InstallSchedulerImpl.setupTasks(InstallSchedulerImpl.java:140)
[5/19/14 17:28:18:052 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R     at com.ibm.ws.management.application.SchedulerImpl.run(SchedulerImpl.java:250)
[5/19/14 17:28:18:052 IST] 0000002d SystemErr     R     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:810)
```

Comment: How exactly are you deploying the application? using scripting? from an IDE? how?

Comment: I am using RAD 7.5 and Websphere Portal and App Server  :

Comment: And how are you deploying?

Comment: Hi the error got resolved :)

Comment: good for you. How about writing an answer here so other people with a similar problem will be able to use it?